# Tikz node values that depend on x

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

In Tikz, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
\foreach \x in {0,...,4}
\draw[fill=black] (\x ,\x *\x ) circle [radius=.2] node[below right] {$(\x,\x*\x)$};
```

The problem is that the node doesn't recognize that I want the second coordinate to be the square of the first; it just writes (0,0*0), (1,1*1), etc.

Is there a clean, simple way to tell Tikz that I want parts of the node to be expressions of \x?

Comment: @marmot He's referring to the node text, not the coordinate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example with `evaluate`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach [evaluate={\y=int(\x*\x)}] \x in {0,...,4}
  \draw[fill=black] (\x ,\x *\x ) circle [radius=.2] node[below right] {$(\x,\y)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```